# Find highest number across row across all workbook

Tags: excel, vba

Find the top 5 highest number (value) on determined row (i.e. row 10) across all tabs in the workbook. Return the "name of the tab" and the value.

```
Sub ShowMinMax()
    Dim vMax

        vMax = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Rows("10"))

    MsgBox "Maximum = " & vMax, vbInformation, "GetMax Values"
End Sub
```

Expected result should be:
"Name of the tab" maxValue1
"Name of the tab" maxValue2
...
"Name of the tab" maxValue5

Comment: One option could be to `Application.Evaluate` a 3-d LARGE formula to get the values, and then a `Find` to figure out what tab they are from.

Comment: [Large does not support 3D references](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/create-a-3-d-reference-to-the-same-cell-range-on-multiple-worksheets-40ca91ff-9dcb-4ad1-99d2-787d0bc888b6)

Comment: @chrisneilsen works for me in Excel 2016, tested using `=LARGE(Sheet1:Sheet5!7:7,1)`. `Evaluate` then worked as well.

Comment: @bigben that's interesting.  Guess it's not the first time MS documentation has let us down

Comment: Yep, completely agree. Looks like `SMALL` is missing as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will iterate the sheets and return the top five numbers and their respective sheets.

```
Sub ShowMinMax()

    Dim MaxArr(1 To 5, 1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim lstColumn As Long
        lstColumn = ws.Cells(10, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Dim rowArr As Variant
        rowArr = ws.Range(ws.Cells(10, 1), ws.Cells(10, lstColumn)).Value
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To lstColumn
            If Not IsEmpty(rowArr) Then
            If IsNumeric(rowArr(1, i)) Then
                Dim j As Long
                For j = 1 To 5
                    If rowArr(1, i) > MaxArr(j, 2) Then
                        Dim k As Long
                        For k = 5 To j + 1 Step -1
                            MaxArr(k, 2) = MaxArr(k - 1, 2)
                            MaxArr(k, 1) = MaxArr(k - 1, 1)
                        Next k
                        MaxArr(j, 2) = rowArr(1, i)
                        MaxArr(j, 1) = ws.Name
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next j
            End If
            End If
        Next i
    Next ws

    'Change line below to the correct output range        
    Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("A15").Resize(5, 2).Value = MaxArr


End Sub
```

This is what I got after running the above:

[image]

Comment: instead of displaying to `Worksheets("Sheet20").Range("A15").Resize(5, 2).Value = MaxArr` to display in to a MsgBox?

Comment: @user3536226 loop through the array and concatenate a text string of the output in the format you want.  Then message box the string.